Implementing mTLS for WebSocket Connection in Next.js with Apollo Client
I'm working on a Next.js app that connects to our GraphQL server using Apollo Client. Recently, I was asked to set up mTLS (mutual TLS) for this GraphQL connection.
I successfully created an internal API route to handle the certificates, allowing me to query data from the server via HTTPS with mTLS. However, since our backend now requires mTLS, the WebSocket connection has stopped working. I’m struggling to figure out how to send the required client certificates through the WebSocket connection, or if it’s even possible to do so from a browser environment.
Has anyone successfully implemented mTLS for a WebSocket connection using Apollo Client in a Next.js app? If so, how did you handle the client certificates? Are there alternative approaches or workarounds to achieve this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
